# weird thing for apache2 with error code 404

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I've find a really really weird thing that've happened to me!
there I set up a apache2 server when I need to build an apt repository

I give all file with privilege 777,so I use command:

```
wget http://10.0.7.180/repo/ncurses-term_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

and it works,but when I download another package there are a 404:

```
wget http://10.0.7.180/vim_2%3a7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
--2018-12-20 22:23:22--  http://10.0.7.180/vim_2%3a7.4.1689- 
 3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
 Connecting to 10.0.7.180:80... connected.
 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
 2018-12-20 22:23:22 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

and at the first time,I guess I make a typo,but so I'll try it again
,it is 404 even I copy paste,so I copy it to root directory,and
`wget with http://xxx/filename` but guess
what?
    same error log again exactly like one before.
    things are exactly out of control:

```
 root@ubuntu:/var/www/html# wget http://10.0.7.180/repo/ssh_1%3a7.2p2-4ubuntu2.6_all.deb
--2018-12-20 22:38:37--  http://10.0.7.180/repo/ssh_1%3a7.2p2-4ubuntu2.6_all.deb
Connecting to 10.0.7.180:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-12-20 22:38:37 ERROR 404: Not Found.

root@ubuntu:/var/www/html# wget http://10.0.7.180/repo/humanity-icon-theme_0.6.10.1_all.deb
--2018-12-20 22:39:01--  http://10.0.7.180/repo/humanity-icon-theme_0.6.10.1_all.deb
Connecting to 10.0.7.180:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1289056 (1.2M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘humanity-icon-theme_0.6.10.1_all.deb’

humanity-icon-theme_0.6.10.1_all.deb             100%[=========================================================================================================>]   1.23M  --.-KB/s    in 0.01s   

2018-12-20 22:39:01 (119 MB/s) - ‘humanity-icon-theme_0.6.10.1_all.deb’ saved [1289056/1289056]
```

Comment: I promise the file is exactly exist and with the right request path

Comment: Perhaps include the relevant Apache configuration and directory listing (or at least the files mentioned here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filenames you use for wget are wrong. `%3a` evaluates to `:`.

The filename is `vim_7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb`.

Comment: That make sense,it is URL Encode Problem,for example `wget http://10.0.7.180/vim_2%3a7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb` are evaluates to `http://10.0.7.180/vim_2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb`?@Sven

Comment: Exactly. I don't know where you get the `2:` in the filename from, the actual name is as I listed.

Comment: e...I am a little confused,for example a short name I mock on a directory,`oneslide%3a.deb`,what's name I use if I use wget?why the ":" is vanished

Comment: `root@ubuntu:/var/www/html# wget http://10.0.7.180/oneslide:.deb

Connecting to 10.0.7.180:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-12-21 02:09:19 ERROR 404: Not Found` it doesn't work@Sven

Comment: Again, where do you get the `:` part of your filename from? It should be `oneslide.deb`, not `oneslide:.deb`. Is `wget http://10.0.7.180/vim_7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb` working?

Comment: No,it doesn't work, I get this question when I try to build local apt repo follow [this](https://odzangba.wordpress.com/2006/10/13/how-to-build-local-apt-repositories/),I package all deb under `/var/cache/apt/archives` and it files name is generated automatically@Sven

Comment: and is there a workaround that I can let apache serve files whose name is special like that? @Sven

Comment: There was an error in my text above, I missed the last `b` from `.deb`. Try with the full name. And AGAIN: Where did you get your strange file names from? The name in the repository is `vim_7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb`, so how do you end up with `vim_2%3a7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb`?

Comment: Also, in the working examples, you have the path `/repo/` in the URL, but you didn't add that at least to the first non-working example. So, does `wget http://10.0.7.180/repo/vim_7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb` work? And `wget http://10.0.7.180/repo/ssh_7.2p2-4ubuntu2.6_all.deb`?

Comment: I indeed correct it last time,it doesn't work,and all those strange names may be when `cp /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb to ~/repo`,and ??It's been a long time,I forgot it.so I need to clean it and copy again? I guess

Comment: Yes,names without `%3a` or like that works @Sven

Comment: my directory info:`root@ubuntu:/var/www/html# ls ./repo
      apt-offline_1.7_all.deb                                                                    
      libice6_2%3a1.0.9-1_amd64.deb                               
       libxcomposite1_1%3a0.4.4-1_amd64.deb` those without %3a works @Sven

Comment: Then something went wrong with creating/copying this repo mirror, the encoded `:` is not a normal part of those file names.

Comment: Thank you,at least I find the origin of problem,even I fail to build a apt repository!but it is unrelavant to this problem,I'll take care of others and  mark you as answer to end this question!@Sven